# Apple configurator 2 could not install app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have designed the ios app and now I want my app to be tested by some other member of team. I generated .ipa as well as .app files of the app. I have install Apple Configurator 2 in my mac os. But when I use that apple configurator to install my app then the app is shown installed in the configurator but in the iPhone the icon shown is dark in color and when I click that nothing happens. But when I deploy app using xcode everything is working good for same configuration.
I don't know what all data is needed to post here for this issue,so if anything is required more than this pls ask.

Comment: You will need to add the device UDID to your provisioning profile in order to install an ad-hoc build on a device

Answer (score 1):

I think there are four things you should confirm.

1. Certificate(Production) is not Expired?
2. Provisioning File(Distribution) is not Expired?.
3. Provisioning File(Distribution) is for AdHoc build (not for App Store)?
4. Provisioning File(Distribution) does contain your device UDID(Paulw11's answer)?

Maybe you need to go developer.apple.com and check your Certificates & Profiles.

[Other possibilities]
If you set date & time of your iOS device manually like 2020/1/29 for testing or something I think app won't run too.

Comment: Is there some kind of workaround to test an AppStore build prior to having it published on the store?

Answer (score 0):

Apple provies "TestFlight" https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

The way how to use it is almost same with submitting an app for review in App Store.

1. Create an App ID
2. Create a provisioning profile with the App ID you created.(Type is "Distribution - App Store")
3. Build an app with the provisioning profile you created.
4. Go App Store Connect and Open "My Apps" and create your app.
5. Upload an app (*.ipa file) to App Store Connect(*1)
6. Go App Store Connect and Open "My Apps" and select an app you uploaded.
7. Select "TestFlight" Tab.
8. Open "Export Compliance" dialog.
9. Answer the question about your app and click next(maybe this step repeats two or three times).
10. Click "Start Internal Testing." (Now you can deliver your beta app in your group.)
11. If you want deliver your app to external tester, add external tester(this needs Apple's app review)

(*1)

Last time I used TestFlight was several years ago, and at that time, I uploaded my app with "Application Loader" but I found this tool is not available now."Transporter" seems like be the alternative.

(*2)

This steps were memo I wrote about two years ago, so some steps may be wrong like Application Loader disappeared in 2019 and need to use Transporter for uploading an app.